# In Python, is there any way to call a child class's method override from its parent class?

Tags: python, inheritance, polymorphism, abstract-class, subclass

I'm trying to re-teach myself Python and figure out the specific details, tips and tricks, and common conventions around abstract classes and polymorphism. Right now, I have a class hierarchy that looks like this:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class A(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def x(self):
        pass

    def do_x_ten_times(self):
        for i in range(10):
            x()


class B(A):

    def x(self):
        print("Hello World")


class C(A):

    def x(self):
        print("Hello StackOverflow")



b = B()
b.x()

c = C()
c.x()

b.do_x_ten_times()
```

My thinking is that *do_x_ten_times()* would be the same exact code in both subclasses **B** and **C**. So it would be convenient (and my code would be less repetitive) if I could just put the code for *do_x_ten_times()* in **A**, and have A call whatever the subclass's implementation of *x()* is. Unfortunately, I get "NameError: name 'x' is not defined."

I get why might not be typical to do something like this, and my gut says that it probably goes against certain rules of polymorphism. If I really need to, I'm fine copypastying *do_x_ten_times()* into both classes **B** and **C**, and making it abstract in **A**. But I'm wondering if there's any reasonable way around having to repeat this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `self.x()` in `A.do_x_ten_times()`

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class A(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def x(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def do_x_ten_times(self):
        for i in range(10):
            self.x()        # <-- self will refer to the calling instance
                            #     implementation of x(self)


class B(A):

    def x(self):
        print("Hello World")


class C(A):

    def x(self):
        print("Hello StackOverflow")



b = B()
b.x()

c = C()
c.x()

b.do_x_ten_times()
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm dumb! Edit: The code I posted was just me quickly making a simple version of a much bigger script where, lo and behold, I made the same exact mistake